# Edit the site analytics privilege help page to reflect DuckDuckGo's changed state

Tags: feature-request, help-center, privileges, site-analytics

[This help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) says one of the known issues with the site analytics is:

> DuckDuckGo shows up as a referring site and not a search engine.

However, that's not the case anymore, so this should be edited out.

Comment: Related on main meta: [Site analytics does not show Duck Duck Go as a referring site anymore, Help Center text should be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327147/241919)

Comment: lite.duckduckgo.com is shown as referring site and so does yandex